# Clustered standard errors vs. serial correlation

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, clustered-standard-errors

I have a probably simple question but I can't find an adequate answer.

I have self-collected data from three monitors that measure temperature, humidity etc. I useed all three monitors simultaneously and now, I want to regress the percent difference of monitor one's results to monitor two's results on local characteristics. I performed 16 measurement sessions and have about 12 paired data points for each session. For the regression, I pool data across all sessions and would like to control for the fact that they are serially correlated within each session.

Is it enough to calculate clustered standard errors because serial correlation is restricted to within-clusters? Or should I do both? And would it be better to additionally include session-dummies?

Thank's a lot in advance!